# Bluemix IoT Foundation Starter app error

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I'm following http://m2m.demos.ibm.com/iotstarter.html. An attempt to connect from an Android app results in the following error messages:

```
3-10 23:14:40.402 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter D/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.fragments.LoginPagerFragment: .handleActivate() entered
03-10 23:14:40.402 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter D/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.iot.IoTClient: .getInstance() entered
03-10 23:14:40.402 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter D/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.iot.IoTClient: .connectDevice() entered
03-10 23:14:40.403 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter D/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.iot.IoTClient: .isMqttConnected() entered 
03-10 23:14:40.403 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter D/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.iot.IoTClient: .isMqttConnected() - 
returning false 03-10 23:14:40.405 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter D/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.iot.IoTClient: Connecting to server: 
tcp://ffjnbk.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883 03-10 
23:14:40.603 2486-10945/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter D/AlarmPingSender: 
Unregister alarmreceiver to MqttServiced:ffjnbk:Android:CCC 03-10 23:14:40.611 2486-2486/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter E/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.utils.MyIoTActionListener: 
.onFailure() entered 03-10 23:14:40.611 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter E/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.utils.MyIoTActionListener: .handleConnectFailure() 
entered 03-10 23:14:40.611 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter E/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.utils.MyIoTActionListener: .handleConnectFailure() - 
Failed with exception 03-10 23:14:40.611 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter 
W/System.err: Not authorized to connect (5) 03-10 23:14:40.611 
2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter W/System.err:     
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException
(ExceptionHelper.java:24) 03-10 23:14:40.611 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter 
W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.notifyReceivedAck
(ClientState.java:815) 03-10 23:14:40.611 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter 
W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run
(CommsReceiver.java:114) 03-10 23:14:40.611 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter 
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 03-10 23:14:40.612 2486-2486/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter D/
com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.fragments.LoginPagerFragment: .onReceive() - 
Received intent for loginBroadcastReceiver 03-10 23:14:40.612 
2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter 
D/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.fragments.LoginPagerFragment: .processIntent() 
entered 03-10 23:14:40.612 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter 
D/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.fragments.LoginPagerFragment: .updateViewStrings() 
entered 03-10 23:14:40.618 2486-2486/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter 
D/com.ibm.iot.android.iotstarter.fragments.LoginPagerFragment: 
.processDisconnectIntent() entered
```

Comment: Are you attempting this from the Dallas or London/UK region? We are currently experiencing issues with London IoT service.

Comment: It was UK. I've tried US and it works.

Comment: For future reference to anyone looking at this post, you can find the status of the Bluemix platform and its services at this URL: http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus

Answer (score 1):

There was on outage on March 10 in UK region.  Full service has been restored, if you are still experiencing the problem today, let us know.